# What size should portfolio thumbnails be? (Wordpress)

Tags: images, image-quality, file-size, image-editing, portfolio

I'm doing my portfolio (graphic design) on Wordpress and I was wondering if you know what the dimensions (in inches or pixels) that I should use for the image of the thumbnail for my portfolio.

Is there a standard thumbnail size we should use? Or is it dependent on the theme we are using? I'm using this theme: http://demo.select-themes.com/stockholm4/three-column-gallery/ 
and they are all the same size boxes rather than masonry.

P.S. are we supposed to design the thumbnail image on indesign or illustrator or photoshop? does it matter? is it best to save it as jpeg (as the other images on my site are saved as jpeg) but I was wondering if we should save in another format for best quality to display as thumbnail?

Thank you!! =))

Answer (score 1):

1) Wordpress will create the thumbnail for you. It depends on the theme you're using for how big the featured image is.

If you have a bunch of images already uploaded and then you applied a theme, You can use the plugin [Regenerate Thumbnail](https://wordpress.org/plugins/regenerate-thumbnails/) to change the thumbnail sizes.

From the plugin page

- A new thumbnail size has been added and you want past uploads to have
  a thumbnail in that size.
- You’ve changed the dimensions of an
  existing thumbnail size, for example via Settings → Media.
- You’ve
  switched to a new WordPress theme that uses featured images of a
  different size.

---

2) You can create the thumbnail in whatever program you're  most comfortable using. Deciding what to save the image as depends on what you're using the image for. Most of the time you will be saving as a JPG.

Comment: Hi, thank you for replying!! I'll keep the plugin in mind if I ever need to use that some day. I applied a theme first and I'm building my website from there as it's my first official portfolio Wordpress site. I understand the site will create thumbnail for you. My question now is if I create a document in indesign at 500 by 500 pixels, my concern is that it will be a tad small that when uploading, the resized thumbnail appears pixelated so that's why I wanted to know like a certain size document to start with so that when uploading, when it gets resized, it still shows clear in the thumbnail

Comment: Would you happen to know a document size to start with? Thanks!! =))

Comment: @LisaWeng I think your themes largest thumbnail is ~400px. So your images should be larger than that. It's common to save images for web around 1000px. I think that is a happy medium between small file size and a somewhat large image.

Comment: I see, thank you for that advice!! =)) So 1000 by 1000 px for the size of the thumbnail image? I'm wondering because the images inside the portfolio projects could also be 1000 by 1000 px. I have images that are like 1000px by around 800px currently. Since the boxes for the thumbnails of this theme are all same size squares, is it recommended to use the same width and height like 1000 by 1000px rather than something like 1000 by 700px? Thank you, wondering =)

Comment: @LisaWeng Hi, your thumbnail would not be he same size as the original image. The thumbnail is sized based on your theme which you can see in Wordpress settings. You can have your images at 1000x700 but your thumbnail might be a 1:1 ratio so it would clip the image until the person clicks on the image to view it at 100%.

Comment: Ooh I see, I have a question, is it conventional to make an image solely for the thumbnail? because in the Wordpress theme that I have (not sure if other themes or regular Wordpress are like this too), in a portfolio post, there is a section that says Featured Image (aka the thumbnail) and I can choose an image to set as the thumbnail. So I can choose an image that will also be inside the post or set an entirely different image that I want to make appear as the thumbnail. is it normal to set a thumbnail image to be something that won't appear inside that particular portfolio post? thanks!! =))

Comment: @LisaWeng We usually make the featured image the thumbnail as well and in my experience I think that is what is most common but you can do whatever you want. There is no rule about it. Like maybe you want a thumbnail but don't want a featured image when the user clicks on the post.